# How to load a template file from my admin controller in custom module in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to load a template file from my admin controller in custom module in prestashop 1.6

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) exit;
 class QueryAllTrxController extends ModuleAdminController
{

public $module;
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}

public function initContent()
{
parent::initContent();
$this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
//$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'mypage.tpl');
}    

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it took forever to figure out.
I ended up spotting the solution in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdnJpLqqvcM

Any this is how I got it to work :

1 - Create the controller in ModuleName/controllers/AdminMyControllerNameController.php

```
class AdminMyControllerNameController extends ModuleAdminController
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->display = 'view';
    $this->meta_title = $this->l('metatitle');
    $this->toolbar_title = $this->l('tollbartitle');
    parent::__construct();
}

public function initContent()
{
    $this->show_toolbar = true;
    $this->display = 'view';
    $this->meta_title = $this->l('META TITLE');

    parent::initContent();

    $this->setTemplate('templatename.tpl');


}

public function initToolBarTitle()
{
    $this->toolbar_title = $this->l('TOOLBAR TITLE??');
}

public function initToolBar()
{
    return true;
}

}
```

2 - Create the template file in ModuleName/views/admin/my_controller_name/template.tpl

You have to create a directory in the views/admin folder using the name of your controller written in snake case.

Anyway I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

## WORKING CODE HERE

**Background:**

You want to add a custom admin page with a custom module controller. But you cannot customize template because you're stuck with this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file '/var/www/html/admin-dev/themes/default/template/catalog/index.tpl' <-- thrown in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 129

Your current source code is:

```php
class AdminYourModuleNameProductsController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent();
        // enable these lines if you're stuck with damn stupid blank page with just 500 error
        // ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        // ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
        // error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $this->setTemplate('products/index.tpl');
    }

}
```

**And you don't know what to do because PrestaShop dev doc is the worst document in the history of ecommerce platform developer document and moreover its forum is full of chitchats and junks.**

### Solution

Place `index.tpl` at

> {%PRESTA_ROOT%}/modules/{%YOUR MODULE DIR%}/views/templates/admin/{% snake case version of controller %}/products/index.tpl

For example, if your module name is `yourmodulename` and the controller name is `AdminYourModuleNameProductsController` (as in the example), the correct path is:

> {%PRESTA_ROOT%}/modules/yourmodulename/views/templates/admin/your_module_name_products/products/index.tpl

### If the error still persists:

Check this [line](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/70d12a5ffbd9f1123e76cded1be8d2f78d5f015c/classes/controller/ModuleAdminController.php#L66):

**{%PRESTA_ROOT%}/classes/controller/ModuleAdminController.php**

```php
public function createTemplate($tpl_name)
{
    if (file_exists(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/'.$tpl_name) && $this->viewAccess()) {
        // echo the following line and exit
        return $this->context->smarty->createTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/'.$tpl_name, $this->context->smarty);
    } elseif (file_exists($this->getTemplatePath().$this->override_folder.$tpl_name) && $this->viewAccess()) {
        // echo the following line and exit
        return $this->context->smarty->createTemplate($this->getTemplatePath().$this->override_folder.$tpl_name, $this->context->smarty);
    }
    // the error occurs because php get reach to the following line:
    return parent::createTemplate($tpl_name);
}
```

Do as I commented and you can get the correct file path. Make sure the file exists in the path.

My PrestaShop version is 1.6.1.24

Answer (score 0):

The code `$this->setTemplate('display.tpl');` is loading a template file `modules/your-custom-module/views/templates/admin/display.tpl` or `modules/your-custom-module/display.tpl`.

Answer (score 0):

The classname must be named that way: AdminQueryAllTrxController

you can put display.tpl in :

```
modules\module_name\views\templates\admin\classe_name(QueryAllTrx)
```

and use :`$this->setTemplate('display.tpl');` in your AdminQueryAllTrxController

Answer (score 0):

First of all add controller to your module:

```
modules\module_name\controllers\admin\SomeNameController.php
```

and extend it by ModuleAdminController, you need at least two methods for it to work properly  __construct and initContent
put the following code to the later method:

```
$this->content .= $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->pathToTpl);

            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'content' => $this->content,
            ));
```

You could replace $this->pathToTpl with any path which is pointed to your tpl file, I'm prefer to create the path dynamically. You can see a simple example here:

```
class SomeNameController extends ModuleAdminController{
  var $pathToTpl;
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();

        $this->pathToTpl = _PS_MODULE_DIR_ .
            $this->module->name .  // put the name of module
            '/views/templates/admin' .
            '/' .
            'templateName.tpl';
        parent::__construct();
    }

  public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        $this->content .= $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->pathToTpl);

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'content' => $this->content,
        ));

    }

}
```

finally you need to place templateName.tpl in the path you wanted to be:

```
modules\module_name\views\templates\admin\templateName.tpl
```

Comment: Shouldn't fetch be called after the assignation of the smarty variables ?